# wordpress apply_filter on same function

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

I found a code snippet in my wordpress theme

```
function jm_resume_custom_fields_prefix() {
        return apply_filters( 'jm_resume_custom_fields_prefix', '_noo_resume_field_' );
    }
```

what does the above code means? How apply filters work in this context?

Answer (score 1):

The action/filter tags and functions are in different namespaces. This means when the function jm_resume_custom_fields_prefix() is executed then all the filters bound to the tag 'jm_resume_custom_fields_prefix' (by add_filter( 'jm_resume_custom_fields_prefix', ...) are applied. The convention of naming the function that does the action/filter the same as the action/filter tag is used heavily in WordPress.